# How to access array in array from react component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, reactjs

I have this array:

```
{
  "firstname": "Jessica",
  "lastname": "Wood",
  "favorite": {
        "movie": Flint Town,
        "drink": Sprite
  }
}
```

I am trying to get drink and i got Objects are not valid as a React child found: object with keys.

How can i fix that?

My react component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Home extends Component {

  state = {
    info: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:9000/api')
      .then(res => {
        const info = res.data;
        this.setState({ info });
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li>{this.state.info.favorite.drink}</li>
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
export default Home;
```

Comment: Is Sprite a string? You would need to convert the values in your "favorite" object to be strings or numbers otherwise you would not be able to render them.

Comment: Hi @slower, is `info` an `Array` or an `Object`

Comment: @ramirozap it is array, when i do this.state.info.firstname it works correctly.

Comment: @slower. Flint Town and Sprite dont seem to be strings. You need to turn them into strings in order for this to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the values inside the "favorite" object so that they can be rendered as strings.

It also looks like you're trying to access a prop in `this.state.info` before it exists. Which is why it gives you the undefined error. The render method runs before you assigned anything to info, which you did in componentDidMount().

To workaround this, we can have a loading-state value to determine what to show. The loading-state will toggle after your componentDidMount() logic has completed, ensuring your state has populated.

Here's the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-germain-k3f23

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    info: {},
    loading: true
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:9000//").then(res => {
      const info = res.data;
      const parsedInfo = {
        ...info,
        favorite: Object.entries(info.favorite).reduce((obj, [k, v]) => {
          obj[k] = "" + v;
          return obj;
        }, {})
      };

      this.setState({ info: parsedInfo, loading: false });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, info } = this.state;
    if (loading) {
      return <div>Loading</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <div>{info.favorite.movie}</div>
          <div>{info.favorite.drink}</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Christopher, with this code i got an error: Line 7:  'myObj' is not defined.

Comment: Oh that's my bad, I meant to say "info" in place of "myObj". See edit above. Thank you @slower

Comment: @slower any luck on implementing the above? Let me know if that gives you any errors, I know I had a typo.

Comment: if i do console.log(this.state.parsedInfo.favorite.drink) in componentDidMount() it works but if i move it to render function it gives me: Cannot read property 'parsedInfo' of null

Comment: @slower. Right because we are accessing a prop in our state that does not yet exist yet. I've added something a little extra in my solution for you. Sorry for not realizing that sooner. :)

Comment: It works. Thanks for help. You just killed that one but its very sad that things like this in javascript is so difficult. I write mostly in php now and it looks like hell when you are beginner like me. :D Anyway thanks for help, you did a great job.

Comment: @slower you're very welcome! and thank you haha. Welcome to the other-side :)